# How to select the properties of an object based on the values of the nested properties of the object using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I want to pick the properties of an object based on the values of the nested properties of the object. I'm using the Lodash `pick()` method as follows.

```
const object = {
  a: {x: true, y: true,}
  b: {x: true, y: false,},
  c: {x: true, y: true,},
};

_.pick(object, y,);
```

I expect to see the following result:

```
{
  a: {x: true, y: true,}
  c: {x: true, y: true,}
}
```

But, instead, I get this error.

> Couldn't run due to Syntax Error on Line 6
>   Unexpected token, expected , (6:2)

What am I doing wrong?

Note: 
If there is no elegant Lodash solution, I'll take an elegant plain Javascript one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`_.pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pickBy), and set the `y` property as the predicate:

```js
const object = {
  a: {x: true, y: true,},
  b: {x: true, y: false,},
  c: {x: true, y: true,},
};

const result = _.pickBy(object, 'y');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Without lodash you can use `Object.entries()` to convert the object to an array of [key, value] pairs, filter by the `y` property of the `value`, and convert back to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const object = {
  a: {x: true, y: true,},
  b: {x: true, y: false,},
  c: {x: true, y: true,},
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(object)
    .filter(([, o]) => o.y)
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax error is actually due to a missing comma in your definition of `object`. `pick` is probably not what you want, how about something like:

```
const object = {
  a: {x: true, y: true,},
  b: {x: true, y: false,},
  c: {x: true, y: true,},
};

_.filter(object, (e) => e.y);
```